# Function that find the smallest int (C)

Tags: c, function, loops, integer

I'm a beginner in C programming and I'm trying to create a function that input numbers and find the smallest of them and display it.So far I did this but it doesn't work:

```
int smallest(){
  int tyy;
  for(tyy=0; tyy<11;tyy++){
    int small;
    int numbers;
    printf("input numbers");
    scanf("%d", &numbers);
    int blockloop;
    while ((blockloop=getchar()) != EOF && blockloop != '\n');
    if (numbers<small){
      numbers = small;
      printf("\n",numbers);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

However this doesn't work, no matter which number I enter it just ask 11 times for numbers and then go back to the main function.I am not quite sure if what I'm doing is correct.

EDIT(but does not print the right number)

```
  int smallest(){
  int tyy;
  for(tyy=0; tyy<11;tyy++){
    int small;
    int numbers;
    printf("input numbers");
    scanf("%d", &numbers);
    int blockloop;
    while ((blockloop=getchar()) != EOF && blockloop != '\n');
    if (numbers<small){
      small=numbers;
      printf("%d\n",numbers);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Input values that were used were 1 to 11; printed result was 11.
thank you!

Comment: First hint - what's the initial value of `small`?  Second hint - what should be the *new* value of `small` if `numbers` is less than `small`?

Comment: `printf("\n",numbers);` should be generating a compiler warning. If not, learn how to increase the warning level on your compiler, or get a better compiler.

Comment: then it should read a vlue,store it,then check if the next one is smaller and replace it if it is? @JohnBode

Comment: Since you are beginning programming in C, you will save yourself a lot of trouble if you compile with warnings enabled. e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra ....` or your compiler equivalent on windows. When you receive warnings, look them up, fix them and then continue. There are only very limited and very rare cases where it is ever OK for you to rely on code that compiles with warnings (you will not encounter any for quite some time).

Comment: The compiler im using is Codeblocks and the last edited code in my question compile with 0 warnings,0 errors

Answer (score 3):

This code doesn't do anything productive that I can see.  It seems to just loop until the user enters EOF or \n.

```
while ((blockloop=getchar()) != EOF && blockloop != '\n');
```

In this code

```
if (numbers<small){
  numbers = small;
  printf("\n",numbers);
}
```

the assignment should be

```
  small = numbers;
```

Also

```
printf("\n",numbers);
```

is not actually outputting your number.  Change it to

```
printf("%d\n",numbers);
```

You need to initialize small to the largest integer.

```
#include <limits.h>
...
int small = INT_MAX;
```

Comment: This is what I just tried and it still doesnt not print the smallest at the end

Comment: Edit your answer to add your new code to the end of the answer (do not overwrite your previous code).  Show the input values you used and the output that you got.  Add a comment here when you have done that so I get a notification.

Comment: Your loop is wrong.  You are getting input 11 different times, and each time separately checking what the smallest number is.  Instead, you should **first** get your eleven numbers (put them in an array), and **then** loop through the array to find the smallest number.

Answer (score 2):

Okay! I managed to fix your code and it's kind of simple so I hope you understand the errors you made:

1. You defined int small and int numbers inside the for loop, that means they live inside for and die everytime the for starts again, that's called a scope. You have to declare the variables outside the scope.

2. You were printing inside the if statement, that meant that it would print the number you just entered.

3. You didn't initialize the variables. You should always do it, specifically if you're comparing them. And when you're doing this kind of programs you should initialize small as the minimum integer so it works as best as possible.

4. I also modified the while, if you entered a char or something that wasn't a number you were just skipping a number, you would not ask for the number again, so I added another scanf inside of it, this could also be done with a goto.

I think that's it! Here's the code:

```
#include <limits.h> 

int smallest(void) {
  int tty, small = INT_MAX, numbers, blockloop;
  for(tty = 0; tty < 11; ++tty) {    
    printf("Input numbers:\n");
    scanf("%d", &numbers);

    while ((blockloop=getchar()) != EOF && blockloop != '\n') {
        scanf("%d", &numbers);
    }

    if(numbers < small) {
      small = numbers;
    }
  }
  printf("Smallest: %d\n", small);
  return 0;
}
```

If you have any question just tell me!

EDIT: Be careful with style, tidy code is easy code, you can spot bugs much faster if the code is well organized. Another one, you should use the name 'i' for variables in for loops, it's just the regular. Also get used to comment your code when something is unclear. And finally, when you find bugs try to run the code in your head, that way you can spot some simple bugs pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to set smallest to INT_MAX. Also using limits.h

```
#include <limits.h>

int smallest(){
  int tyy;
  for(tyy=0; tyy<11;tyy++){
    int small = INT_MAX;
    int numbers;
    printf("input numbers");
    scanf("%d", &numbers);
    int blockloop;
  while ((blockloop=getchar()) != EOF && blockloop != '\n');
    if (numbers<small){
      small = numbers;
    printf("\n",numbers);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while` loop needs a `scanf("%d", &numbers);`

Comment: Also my function doesnt seem to display anything at the end(print the smallest)

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your `int` variables before using them.

`small` has an indeterminate value because it is uninitialized, so your program can't tell if `numbers` is less than `small` at your if statement:

```
 if (numbers < small)
```

`small` needs to be initialized to a large value (known to be larger than expected input numbers), or to the first input value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's just a quick fix to your code. I hope it helps to understand where the problem is.

Please, take into account what others have written so far: there are a lot of useful hints and remarks that will help you improve your code quality.

```
int smallest(){
  int tyy;
  int small=INT_MAX;                // (1)
  for(tyy=0; tyy<11;tyy++){
//     int small;                   // Moved outside the loop and initialized - See (1)
    int numbers;
    printf("input numbers");
    scanf("%d", &numbers);
    int blockloop;
    while ((blockloop=getchar()) != EOF && blockloop != '\n');
    if (numbers<small){
      small=numbers;
//       printf("%d\n",numbers);    // Removed
    }
  }
  printf("%d\n",small);             // Added - Print the smallest
  return 0;
}
```

To be able to use INT_MAX you have to include the proper header.

```
#include <limits.h>                 // Provides the INT_MAX symbolic constant
```

Below there's an example of how the program could be written according to a few basic principles such as

- *functional decomposition* - each function performs a single, well defined task
- *variable initialization* - each variable is properly initialized before being used
- *code readability* - each entity is given a proper, hopefully meaningful name; symbolic constants are used in place of magic numbers; whitespaces are added to highlight code structure

Here's the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define NUM_TO_BE_READ   11

// Find and return the smallest number in the given array of ints
int FindSmallest( int numbers[], unsigned int size ){
    int   smallest   =   numbers[ 0 ];
    int   i          =   1;

    for ( i = 1; i < size; i++ ){
        if ( numbers[ i ] < smallest ){
        smallest   =   numbers[ i ];
        }
    }

    return smallest;
}

// The main function - program entry point
int main(){
    // Define and initialize a few variables
    int   numbers[ NUM_TO_BE_READ ];
    int   smallest   =   INT_MAX;
    int   i          =   0;

    for ( i = 0; i < NUM_TO_BE_READ; i++ )
    {
    numbers[ i ]   =   INT_MAX;
    }

    // Read numbers
    for ( i = 0; i < NUM_TO_BE_READ; i++ )
    {
    printf( "number: " );
    scanf( "%d", &numbers[ i ] );
    }

    // Find the smallest number
    smallest   =   FindSmallest( numbers, NUM_TO_BE_READ );

    // Print the smallest number and exit
    printf("The smallest number is: %d\n", smallest );
    return 0;
}
```